# Does my Bootcamp partition, disappeared by Lion install, still exist?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, partition

I installed Lion on my macbook air, and noticed a couple of days later that my bootcamp partition was gone--rebooting with option key no longer showed the volume, and diskutil shows the following

```
ccaajj-mba:~ ccaajj$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         120.5 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS metta                  *120.2 GB   disk1
```

It's a 128GB SSD, so looks like my 20GB bootcamp partition is toast.

Any ideas? I'm wondering if the volume and data is still there but the partition map is hosed and just not showing it. Thanks in advance y'all!

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't look good for your boot camp partition.  Take a look at the drive layout in Disk Utility.app (in /Applications/Utilities, accessible from Launchpad), which visualizes the entire drive in slices.  If you don't see the 20GB slice there, then it has been overwritten.

Did you obtain Lion from the App Store?

Comment: Did get Lion from app store. Oddly, Disk Utility did initially show what seemed to be my main partition overlapping with another that looked to be about the right size. Which is why I thought the data was still there but maybe the lion recovery partition "stole" the volume ID or something.