# Upgrading a boot camp machine to Lion

Tags: macos, bootcamp, upgrade

I have a Snow Leopard MacBook Air with Boot Camp installed. I'm thinking about upgrading to Lion, but I'm worried about all the software I have installed on my Boot Camp partition. I have a lot of software, including Windows, which uses serial keys and product activation to ensure that I'm running a legal version. I'm worried that if something happens to this partition, all my keys will remain in use on an unusable drive.

If I upgrade Snow Leopard to Lion, will the Boot Camp partition remain untouched and still work properly?

I read [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20698/does-my-bootcamp-partition-disappeared-by-lion-install-still-exist) which made me cautious about upgrading until I know for certain that nothing will happen to the Boot Camp partition. Are there any guides specifically meant to show you how to upgrade to Lion and still retain your boot camp partition?

Are there any other steps that need to be done once the upgrade is complete? Is the Boot Camp software from Snow Leopard compatible with Lion? Is it easily upgradable?

Answer (score 1):

It should be fine. Just make sure to select the right disk (`Macintosh HD`) when installing Lion. A backup never hurts, either.

Answer (score 1):

You should be good to go. You should always have a complete backup before performing a major upgrade of course. I’ve already helped a friend upgrade to Lion on a MacBook Pro with a Boot Camp partition and everything was fine.

Apple has a pretty good [BootCamp FAQ](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4818) related to Lion.